# setting model from route upon action received in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set a model value from an action received by my route.

```
//app/routes/map.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      trail: null
    };
  },
  actions: {
    event: function(name, value) {
      if (name === 'trail.selected') {
        this.modelFor('map').set('trail', value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

when I try to use

```
 this.modelFor('map').set('trail', value);
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.modelFor(...).set is not a function

When I try to use

```
this.modelFor('map').trail = value;
```

I get that error

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `trail` property (of [object Object]) to `<nested-component@model:mtg-trail::ember617:kvdpo>`.

**EDIT Added template**

```
//app/templates/map.hbs
<h2>Trail's name: {{trail.name}}</h2>
{{#if trail}}
  {{map-draw trail=trail.id}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: has the map route loaded? i.e is it a parent in the same hierarchy? If not you won't be able to set it in that manner

Comment: I don't understand your question, I use sendAction from a component in a didInsertElement under that route hierarchy so I guess it is loaded.

Comment: actually I see your route is the index route, so map cannot be a parent route. Why do you need to set the model on a route and model that isn't active at the moment?

Comment: Oh my bad, I have a typo, the route is map.js sorry, I update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes model isn't an ember object so `set` won't work. Try:

```
  model: function() {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      trail: null
    });
  },
```

Also, changing the models content from an action should really be done on the controller.

Comment: I'm trying to refactor an existing application as ember 2.0 compliant, so I am trying to avoid the use of controllers.

Comment: Well components should be used instead of controllers then, but until routable components are available, controllers may still be necessary!

Comment: I've tried your solution, I don't get the error anymore but the rendering doesn't reflect the change in the model...

Comment: Ok, I found the problem is that I had to get the firstObject from the promise array, found it after some more debuging

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the action you are calling is on the 'map' route itself, why not just:

```
this.set('model.trail', value);
```